# Outlook 365 shared calendar appointments showing on week view, but how to show all of them permanently

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar, list, appointments

We have Outlook 365 that uses shared calendar.
We have on week view showing appointments at the top of the screen.
But here is the problem:
could that list be showed as a bigger list(ex. all appointments on that day)?

Now it shows about ten appointments, but if there is more,
 it leaves them behind a button to load all appointments.
I tried to look from settings but didn't see anything than minimized and normal or off.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the button is as shown in the figure below?
[image]

If so, this is to remind you of the number of obscured calendar items when sliding down to view the calendar, so as to prevent these items from being ignored. It's by design. And just slide the calendar up to see all the calendar items.

If the above is not your case, please provide screenshots about the botton so that we can understand the issue more clearly. (In order to avoid the disclosure of your privacy, please remember to hide your personal information)

Comment: You got it right on the first try.
It can't be overrun? We would like to have all the appointments showing.

Comment: Through my research, i didn't find an option to disable it. As a workaround, it's suggested that you could adjust the zoom setting in the lower right corner so that the week view doesn't need to slide and all appointments will not be collapsed.